# How to create dynamic variables from SQL results

Tags: php, sql

This one should be easy and it's killing me I can't find the solution!

I have a SQL query return records from a database. The two fields I am using are $row["staff_id"] and $row["name"].

From that I want to build a dynamic variable which is something like:

```
$staffid_1 = "Mark Smith";
$staffid_2 = "Sally Baker";
$staffid_3 = "Peter Pan";
```

The varibale name is created dynamically be combining "staffid_" and $row["staff_id"] for the first part then $row["name"] for the name.

I've tried:

```
${$staff_id . $row["staff_id"]} = $row["name"];
echo ${$staff_id . $row["staff_id"]} . "<br>";
```

But no luck! Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: where'd you get `$staff_id`? its not yet initialized. `${'staffid_' . $row['staff_id']}`

Comment: then `echo $staffid_1;` i'd stay away from this though, why would you want this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you might be best to change your query to return the first part of it, then whatever you're calling it from to concatenate it together, eg

Query:

```
SELECT '$staffid_' + ltrim(rtrim(cast(staff_id as varchar))) + ' = "' + name + '"' 
FROM [table list]
ORDER BY  ...
```

Then concatenate the individual rows of result set as required, with 
 in-between as you seem to require.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in PHP you have an awesome option to use a double leveled variable which basically means this :

```
$$varname = $value;
```

This results in the fact that if you have a string variable ,
(for example `$staffid = "staffid_1"`) that you can do the following:

```
$staffid = "Jasonbourne";
$$staffid = "Matt Damon";
// Will result in
$JasonBourne = "Matt Damon";
```

So for your example:

```
$name = "staffid_" . $row["staff_id"];
$$name = $row["name"];
```

Will result in the variable : `$staff_id_1 = "Mark Smith";`

> To read more about double - leveled variables :
>   http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

**EDIT: If you wanna loop through the rows :**

```
foreach ($sql_result as $row) {
    $name = "staffid_" . $row["staff_id"];
    $$name = $row["name"];
}
```